# An invisible prompt overlays my wordpress website homepage and wont close on clicking x

Tags: wordpress, web, overlay, frontpage

I recently had an issue with the host and after it got resolved, a slightly transparent overlay covers my homepage when you click anywhere.

The x button also doesn't work, and the overlay only leaves when you hit escape on the keyboard.

It also doesn't leave when I let it idle.

I can however access other pages if I right-click and open anything in a new tab.

https://regentcollegeabuja.com/

How the homepage reacts to clicks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've inspected your code, and you have a jquery error. This is coming from swipebox plugin. You can try to fix the issues by following the steps.

**1) Update your WordPress core, themes, all plugins after updating test your site from the guest window. Sometimes resolve the issue by this way.**

**2) Deactivate the plugin and activated it again.**

**3) Inspect your code, understand the problem and update the JS file.**

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your response. I don't have the swipebox plugin installed on the website and all the plugins are updated, except for WP Bakery builder at the moment.